Book hour to R&R Silverado transmission
How many hours does the book give to r&r a 2 wheel drive automatic transmission on a 2008 5.3 chevy silverado 1/2 ton?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

To whomever put a VTC on this question as a "shopping question", this is an on-topic question. We have a few of these questions on the site. While they very rarely get answered, they are not off-topic. The reason is, the question is answerable, it doesn't change, it isn't localized, and it isn't asking "how much does it cost". It's just asking for labor hours which comes out of a book.
